# UIPopoverController dismisses when touched inside

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

I have a simple UIPopoverController which loads a Youtube page. All works fine except the popover seems to randomly dismiss when touches are made *inside* it's bounds.

This doesn't seem to be consistent (as to which touches cause the dismiss, although it is never the first one), has anyone else seen this behaviour?

Code i'm using below, the URL being loaded is just for testing.

```
-(void)showWebPopover
{
    UIWebView * webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, WEBVIEW_POPOVER_WIDTH, WEBVIEW_POPOVER_HEIGHT)];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M"]]];
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
//webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

UIViewController *popOver = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
popOver.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, WEBVIEW_POPOVER_WIDTH, WEBVIEW_POPOVER_HEIGHT);
popOver.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
popOver.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(WEBVIEW_POPOVER_WIDTH, WEBVIEW_POPOVER_HEIGHT);
[popOver.view addSubview:webView];

self.webViewPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popOver];

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.width/2, 1, 1);
[self.webViewPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could add your code

Comment: Just ran into this and I solved it by attaching a UITapGestureRecognizer to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late, but I just ran into this and solved it by attaching a UITapGestureRecognizer to the view controller.  (not the PopoverController, but the controller the PopoverController uses.)

i.e.

```
    func present (title:String, body:String, footer:String, sourceRect:CGRect) {
    if let fPopup = self.storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GuideViewController") as? GuideViewController {
        popoverController = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: fPopup)
        fPopup.titleLabel.text = title
        fPopup.bodyTextField.text = body
        fPopup.footerLabel.text = footer

        //these 4 lines to set it up
        var touchRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer( target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
        touchRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        touchRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        fPopup.view.addGestureRecognizer(touchRecognizer)


        popoverController?.presentPopoverFromRect(sourceRect, inView: parentView, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
    }
}

func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .Ended {
        popoverController?.dismissPopoverAnimated(true)
    }
}
```